# VBA function just yielding zero. Cannot figure out why

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

When I manually do it in Excel, I get a different number than what the VBA function does. The function is shown below.

```
Function TimeEstimate(InstanceCount As Integer, Grouping As Integer, DaysPerBoard As Integer,  _
       MinRunTime As Integer, XShift As Integer)
    If InstanceCount <= 0 Then
        TimeEstimate = 0
    ElseIf Application.RoundUp((InstanceCount + XShift) / Grouping, 0) * Grouping * DaysPerBoard < MinRunTime Then
        TimeEstimate = MinRunTime
    Else
       TimeEstimate = Application.RoundUp((InstanceCount + XShift) / Grouping, 0) * Grouping * DaysPerBoard
    End If
End Function
```

Some example data:

Instance Count: 1
   Grouping: 10
   DaysPerBoard:0.03
   MinRunTime:0.5
   XShift:0

When properly calculated you should get 0.5 (the MinRuntime), but I get zero.

Comment: Why are your argument types all `Integer`s? `0.03` and `0.5` are not `Integer`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your variables are defined as `integer`. Use `double` for the decimals, instead